# How java string.replaceAll method works to trim only right end using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I tried two different regex both seems correct to me, however first one doesn't return correct output.

My Question:
I want to understand why it gives different results
and what's wrong regex or its usage.

```
String cleaned_input = "Hello\n\tWorld, Test\\\\\\\\data\\\\\\";

1. String output = cleaned_input.replaceAll("\\+$", "").trim();
2. String output = cleaned_input.replace("[\\\\*]+$", "").trim();
```

Output 1:

```
Hello
    World, Test\\\\data\\\
```

Output 2:

```
Hello
    World, Test\\\\data
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because in this regex:

```
"\\+$"
```

you're just matching literal `+` before end anchor.

2nd regex is correctly matching 1 or more backslash before end of line but in a  unnecessary character class with `*`. 2nd regex can better be written as:

```
String output = cleaned_input.replaceAll("\\\\+$", "");
```

Comment: Java's string.replace method doesn't expect string-as-regex pattern matching object